# Can garage and living space lighting be on same circuit?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

In california, by code, can a single 15A afci circuit serve both attached garage and living space lighting?

Comment: attached garage?

Comment: Attached garage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is fine

There are no requirements for dedicated *lighting* circuits anywhere in a dwelling unit; in fact, with LEDs, having all your lights on a single circuit isn't that far-fetched an idea in this day and age.  So, since your circuit is AFCI protected, it meets the requirements for living room lighting, and since the garage is attached, it can share house circuits, by and large.  (Note that the 2020 NEC requires a dedicated 20A circuit for garage *receptacles*, but this has no bearing on the garage *lighting* circuit.)

Comment: Though putting all your lighting on **TWO** circuits, alternating rooms, makes some sense. It allows for both turning off a circuit for maintenance (e.g., replacing a fixture) without putting the whole house in the dark (obviously for the room you are working on you can use LED flashlights, but this avoids inconveniencing everyone else) and it also means if the AFCI trips due to wiring problems, you still have 1/2 the lights working.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact one could even use _incandescent_ flashlights! _Gasp!!_  :)